# Snowflake User level credit monitor

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on creating user level monitor of credit usage on a monthly level, And have created a small query as per below.

```
Select user_name, 
sum(CREDITS_USED_CLOUD_SERVICES) credit_used, 
date_trunc(month, current_date) month,
Warehouse_name
from query_history
where start_time >= date_trunc(month, current_date)
group by 1,3,4
order by 2 desc;
```

And it seems to be working however there is only one confusion. the Credit_usage field is named as
CREDITS_USED_CLOUD_SERVICES in snowflake, which makes me think it is only providing me the credit usage of service layer and not warehouse layer. If so then this query is not good? and If my concern is right, can somebody please suggest or guide me to correct path of how to get the credit usage per user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67586894/how-to-reduce-and-monitor-compute-resources-in-snowflake

Comment: @GregPavlik Thanks Greg.. that link will help. however can you suggest what exactly does CREDITS_USED_CLOUD_SERVICES means.. I just want to confim my thought process.

Comment: Cloud services is an architectural layer that sits above the warehouse in Snowflake's three-level architecture:  Cloud Services, Warehouse, Data. When an account's CS compute usage is under 10% of overall compute, it is not chargeable. When CS is greater than 10% the portion over 10% is chargeable. That's why the ACCOUNT_USAGE schema shares that information. There will always be CS credits used for queries, though the effect may be so small it rounds to zero for several decimal places. They only are chargeable for a small fraction of customers since normal usage keeps them under 10%.